# "Find the volume of the ellipsoid $x^2+\frac{y^2}{100}+\frac{z^2}{4} = 1$" was the question and here's my attempt.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, volume, multiple-integral

So, I asked this question and got downvotes and someone saying I should present my attempt. Here lies my thought process:

I know the volume is $\iiint dxdydz$ on any W$\subset R^3$ and I "just" had to find the proper values for the W, namely x, y, z, their range.

I said $-1≤x≤1$, $-10≤y≤10$ and $-2≤z≤2$.

Expressing them on the integral, for every variable we set the next one to 0 and the previous as constant so it's:

$-1≤x≤1$

$-10 \sqrt{1-x^2} ≤y≤10 \sqrt{1-x^2}$

$-2 \sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{100}} ≤ z ≤ 2 \sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{100}}$

and it actually went from $dxdydz$ to $dzdydz$

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, I don't think this is a correct solution, and that's why I'd appreciate a hint, or where I'm wrong.

Comment: Please use substitution $x = X, y = 10Y, z = 2Z$. Find Jacobian and then you transform the region to a unit sphere. Do you know how to find volume of a unit sphere? If so, you are done.

Comment: The volume of an ellipsoid with semi-axes $a,b,c$ is $\dfrac43 \pi abc$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid)

Comment: Thank you, is my attempt in any way right?

Comment: For me it is right. Integration is $dz\, dy\, dx.$ Nevertheless, i would use generalized spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did is correct. Translating it into an integral in Cartesian coordinates, it becomes$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-10\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{10\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{-2\sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{100}}}^{2\sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{100}}}1\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$You can compute it as follows:\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1\int_{-10\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{10\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{-2\sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{100}}}^{2\sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{100}}}1\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx&=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-10\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{10\sqrt{1-x^2}}4\sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{100}}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_{-1}^120\pi(1-x^2)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\frac{80}3\pi.\end{align}However, the computation becomes much easier if you do the change of coordinates$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x=X\\y=10Y\\z=2Z\end{array}\right.$$Then your integral becomes$$20\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-^2}}^{\sqrt{1-X^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{1-X^2-Y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-X^2-Y^2}}1\,\mathrm dZ\,\mathrm dY\,\mathrm dX,\tag1$$since, other than the factor $20$, $(1)$ is the volume of the unit sphere, which is $\frac43\pi$. So you get, again, that the answer is $\frac{80}3\pi$.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for not vote on positive answers like this.

Comment: Yes, the easier method is what I would have told OP.